# Parsing an html document using an XML-parser

Tags: html, xml, parsing, html-parsing

Can I parse an HTML file using an XML parser?

Why can('t) I do this. I know that XML is used to store data and that HTML is used to display data. But syntactically they are almost identical.

The intended use is to make an HTML parser, that is part of a web crawler application

Comment: you can do it as long as your html is strict XML (like XHTML 1.0 for instance). Otherwise, HTML is not strictly XML and thus, parsers will raise errors.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can try parsing an HTML file using a XML parser, but it’s likely to fail. The reason is that HTML documents can have the following HTML features that XML parsers don’t understand.

- elements that **never have end tags** and that don’t use XML’s so-called “self-closing tag syntax”; e.g., **`<br>`**, **`<meta>`**, **`<link>`**, and **`<img>`** (also known as *void* elements)
- elements that **don’t need end tags**; e.g., **`<p>`** **`<dt>`** **`<li>`** (their end tags can be *implied*)
- elements that can contain **unescaped markup** "`<`" characters; e.g., **style**, **textarea**, **title**, **script**; `<script> if (a < b) … </script>`, `<title>Using the "<" operator</title>`
- attributes with **unquoted** values; for example, `<meta` **`charset=utf-8`**`>`
- attributes that are **empty**, with no separate value given at all; e.g., `<input` **`disabled`**`>`

XML parsers will fail to parse any HTML document that uses any of those features.

HTML parsers, on the other hand, will basically never fail no matter what a document contains.

---

All that said, there’s also been work done toward developing a new type of XML parsing: so-called **XML5 parsing**, capable of handling things like empty/unquoted attributes attributes even in XML documents. There is a [draft XML5 specification](https://ygg01.github.io/xml5_draft/), as well [as an XML5 parser, xml5ever](https://github.com/Ygg01/xml5ever).

---

> The intended use is to make an HTML parser, that is part of a web
> crawler application

If you’re going to create a web-crawler application, you should absolutely use an HTML parser—and ideally, an HTML parser that conforms to the [parsing requirements in the HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#parsing).

These days, there are such conformant HTML parsers for many (or even most) languages; e.g.:

- [parse5](https://github.com/inikulin/parse5) (node.js/JavaScript)
- [html5lib](https://github.com/html5lib/html5lib-python) (python)
- [html5ever](https://github.com/servo/html5ever) (rust)
- [validator.nu html5 parser](https://about.validator.nu/htmlparser/) (java)
- [gumbo](https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser) (c, with [bindings for ruby, objective c, c++, per, php, c#, perl, lua, D, julia…](https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser#external-bindings-and-other-wrappers))

---

Answer (score 10):

> syntactically they are almost identical

Computers are picky. "Almost identical" isn't good enough. HTML allows things that XML doesn't, therefore an XML parser will reject (many, though not all) HTML documents.

In addition, there's a different quality culture. With HTML the culture for a parser is "try to do something with the input if you possibly can". With XML the culture is "if it's faulty, send it back for repair or replacement".