# Parse HTML table with Oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I need to parse an HTML table:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="blue"><td>code</td><td>rate</td></tr>
    <tr class="gray_1"><td><span>USD</span><em>1</em></td><td>476.16</td></tr>
    <tr class="gray_2"><td><span>AUD</span><em>1</em></td><td>327.65</td></tr>
    <tr class="gray_9"><td><span>IRR</span><em>100</em></td><td>1.13</td></tr>
    <tr class="blue"><td>some comment</td><td>some comment</td></tr>
    <tr class="gray_1"><td><span>EUR</span><em>1</em></td><td>526.54</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and as a result to get:

```
+------+----+----+------+
|class |code|em  |value |
+------+----+----+------+
|gray_1|USD |   1| 11.11|
|gray_2|AUD |   1| 22.22|
|gray_9|IRR | 100| 33.33|
|gray_1|EUR |   1| 44.44|
```

I tried to do it like this:

```
with tbl as
(
    select xmltype('
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr class="blue"><td>code</td><td>rate</td></tr>
            <tr class="gray_1"><td><span>USD</span><em>1</em></td><td>476.16</td></tr>
            <tr class="gray_2"><td><span>AUD</span><em>1</em></td><td>327.65</td></tr>
            <tr class="gray_9"><td><span>IRR</span><em>100</em></td><td>1.13</td></tr>
            <tr class="blue"><td>some comment</td><td>some comment</td></tr>
            <tr class="gray_1"><td><span>EUR</span><em>1</em></td><td>526.54</td></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
    ') xml_data from dual
)
select
    *
from
    tbl,
    xmltable('//table/tbody/tr'
        passing tbl.xml_data
        columns
            data varchar2(128) path './td'
    )
```

But this causes an exception:

> ORA-19279: XPTY0004 - XQuery dynamic type mismatch: expected singleton sequence - got multi-item sequence

What do I need to do to fix my code?

Comment: XML is not fully compatible with HTML so using XML methods on HTML is not recommended.

Comment: @jdweng I realize that, but is there a better way to parse html with Oracle? I need to get and parse html page by schedule, so I do it using an oracle job which calls a pl/sql procedure.
I just find certain piece if a page, then throw away tags like <br>, &nbsp; etc. to get a code that could be parsed like an XML code

Comment: Most people recommend HtmlAgilityPack.  I really don't think it that bad to use xml, but every time I do it I get lots of negative points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `path` is looking for a `td` under the `tr`; but there are two, hence the "got multi-item sequence" error you're seeing. You can reference each `td` tag by its position, as `td[1]` etc. It's very reliant on the table structure being as expected though.

With this specific example you can do:

```
with tbl as
(
    select xmltype('
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr class="blue"><td>code</td><td>rate</td></tr>
            <tr class="gray_1"><td><span>USD</span><em>1</em></td><td>476.16</td></tr>
            <tr class="gray_2"><td><span>AUD</span><em>1</em></td><td>327.65</td></tr>
            <tr class="gray_9"><td><span>IRR</span><em>100</em></td><td>1.13</td></tr>
            <tr class="blue"><td>some comment</td><td>some comment</td></tr>
            <tr class="gray_1"><td><span>EUR</span><em>1</em></td><td>526.54</td></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
    ') xml_data from dual
)
select
    x.class, x.currency, x.amount, to_number(x.rate) as rate
from
    tbl
cross join
    xmltable('/table/tbody/tr'
        passing tbl.xml_data
        columns
            class varchar2(10) path '@class',
            currency varchar2(3) path 'td[1]/span',
            amount number path 'td[1]/em',
            rate varchar2(50) path 'td[2]'
    ) x
where
    x.currency is not null
```

which gets:

```
CLASS      CUR     AMOUNT       RATE
---------- --- ---------- ----------
gray_1     USD          1     476.16
gray_2     AUD          1     327.65
gray_9     IRR        100       1.13
gray_1     EUR          1     526.54
```

It won't take much variation in the HTML to break it though. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32573619/266304) for some reasons it is fragile, and why it generally considered unwise to try to parse HTML as XML.